# How to get the resource types from a webpage using JSoup?

Tags: types, groovy, resources, jsoup, crawler4j

I am trying to make a webcrawler in Groovy. I am looking to extract the resource types from a webpage. I need to check if a particular webpage has the following resource types:

PDFs

JMP Files

SWF Files

ZIP Files

MP3 Files

Images

Movie Files

JSL Files

I am working with crawler4j for crawling and JSoup for parsing.
In general I would like to know any approach for getting any resource type that I may need in future. I tried the following in my BasicCrawler.groovy. It just tells the content type of the page i.e. text/html or text/xml. I need to get all the types of resource on that page. Please correct me where I am going wrong:

```
@Override
void visit(Page page) {
    println "inside visit"
    int docid = page.getWebURL().getDocid()
    url =  page.getWebURL().getURL()
    String domain = page.getWebURL().getDomain()
    String path = page.getWebURL().getPath()
    String subDomain = page.getWebURL().getSubDomain()
    parentUrl = page.getWebURL().getParentUrl()
    String anchor = page.getWebURL().getAnchor()
    println("Docid: ${docid} ")
    println("URL: ${url}  ")
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements nextLinks = doc.body().select("[href]");
    for( Element link : nextLinks ) {
        String contentType = new URL(link.attr("href")).openConnection().getContentType();
        println url + "***" + contentType
    }
    if (page.getParseData() instanceof HtmlParseData) {
        HtmlParseData htmlParseData = (HtmlParseData) page.getParseData()
        String text = htmlParseData.getText()
        String html = htmlParseData.getHtml()
        List<WebURL> links = htmlParseData.getOutgoingUrls()

    }
    println("FINISHED CRAWLING")
    def crawlObj = new Resource(url : url)
    if (!crawlObj.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)) {
        crawlObj.errors.each { println it }
    }
}
```

After printing two doc ids, it throws the error: `ERROR crawler.WebCrawler - Exception while running the visit method. Message: 'unknown protocol: tel' at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:592)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for all URLs in the Document and ask the server for the content type. 
Here is a quick+dirty example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://yourpage").get();
Elements elements = doc.body().select("[href]");
for (Element element : elements) {
    String contentType = new URL(element.attr("href")).openConnection().getContentType();
}
```

For images, embedded elements and so on you should search for the `src` attribute.

Comment: I will accept it as soon as I try. It looks like exactly what I might need. Thanks.

Comment: Content Type will just tell about text/html I think. I need to know the  varies resources that are mentioned on the webpage.

Comment: If the server does not lie to you he will return the Content-Type for the requested document. For instance `application/pdf` for a pdf-file or `application/zip` for a zip-file. Be sure to try it on a page which does not only link to other html-pages.

Comment: You mean that content type would enlist all the different types of content(like mentioned above) for a webpage? Thanks. I didn't know this. I will try. :)

Comment: Like I had thought, it just told me about text/html and text/xml. It did not tell about all the resource types in a page

Comment: I didnt get you. could you please elaborate

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you add the url you are parsing to your example.

Comment: Ok I updated the question. Basically I have integrated crawler4j with jsoup

Comment: My example code is working for this url if you search for the `src` attribute. For the `href` attribute you are always getting `text/html` because all links are pointing to other html sites. I can't find a link to a pdf or any other file on this page.

Comment: For me, after printing two doc ids, it throws the error: ERROR crawler.WebCrawler  - Exception while running the visit method. Message: 'unknown protocol: tel' at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:592)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56669/discussion-between-lefloh-and-ayushi).

Answer (score 2):

Apache Tika covers a lot of those formats

http://tika.apache.org

> The Apache Tika™ toolkit detects and extracts metadata and structured text content from various documents using existing parser libraries.

And those that it doesn't, you should be able to write a recogniser

Comment: So would you suggest using different libraries for different functionality in the same project? Would it lead to any conflicts? I am using JSoup for some other parts of this project that's why I wanted to know.

Comment: Not sure how an HTML parser will detect pdfs

Comment: I just want to know if a webpage contains any pdf files. Do you think that's not possible?

Comment: You could scan for links ending in PDF, but you'll get some false positives and miss some if they are being done sort of processing

Comment: I am thinking that JSoup can work with CSS Selectors. There is a CSS Selector :
[attribute$=value] a[src$=".pdf"] Selects every <a> element whose src attribute value ends with ".pdf"

Do you think I can use this for getting all the resources from a page?